# ios geocodeAddressString modify global variable during block

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, clgeocoder

I understand that the call to CLGeocoder geocodeAddressString is asynchronous, with a block passed in to handle the callback at completion time.  I also understand that the only variables that are mutable within the block are local __block variables.  But I need to store the resulting CLPlacemarks in a global NSMutableArray variable, and I can't work out how that can happen.  Any __block variables can only be accessed within the same method, but at the point that they have any value (i.e. within the block) I can't assign any value to the global array.  After the block, the __block variables will likely not have any value because of the immediate return when calling the async geocodeAddressString.

How can I store the results of the call, so that they can be used to update a UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.  I was incorrectly deducing (from my reading about blocks) that properties and instance variables could not be modified within the scope of a block.  In my case, the reason I couldn't modify my iVar array was that I hadn't alloc/init'ed it.  Once I did that, I was able to assign values and see them outside of the block e.g. in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method of my table view.

Apologies to anyone who may have been misled by my initial assumptions!  For the record, I do think that the text on the Apple docs re blocks & variables [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html) is a bit misleading...the only variables that it mentions as being mutable are the __block function-level variables, whereas it says all others "can be accessed" which I took as meaning "read-only" (I know that both getters and setters are accessors, but the context was confusing).

Comment: You are always accessing (i.e. reading the value of) an object pointer variable to send a message to or access the fields of the object it points to. Changing a variable means assigning to it.